# Olympic problem - Probability

Tags: probability, contest-math

A jar contains 3 cookies filled with chocolate, 4 cookies filled with strawberry and 3 cookies filled with vainilla. What is the probability of choosing 3 cookies with the same filling from the jar?

*EDIT*: I've tried this:

What I want to find is:

$$\frac{Favorable\ outcomes}{Possible\ outcomes}$$
Since I only care about choosing three cookies, I think the possible outcomes are $\binom{10}{3}$.

Now, the favorable outcomes should be: 6.
Only one option to get the three chocolate filled cookies, same with the vanilla filling. I have $\binom{4}{3}=4$ ways to choose three cockies from the strawberry cookies.

Now, the probability I want should be:
$$\frac{1+1+\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{6}{120}=\frac{1}{20}.$$

But I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Comment: I'd solve it, but you need to show some _initial thoughts_ of yours...

Comment: I just edited. Sorry, I forgot to post what I tried.

Comment: Well done! Your solution is great.

Comment: That is exactly how I would go about this, and it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the problem as a choice tree and ask yourself: how many branches do I have that satisfy the conditions above?

In this case you have a tree with depth three (3). How many branch ends are there to satisfy your condition, and what is the probability of getting to each of them?

P(3 vanilla) = $\frac{3}{10} * \frac{2}{9} * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{6}{720}$

P(3 straberry) = $\frac{4}{10} * \frac{3}{9} * \frac{2}{8} = \frac{24}{720}$

P(3 chocolate) = $\frac{3}{10} * \frac{2}{9} * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{6}{720}$

Sum it up and you get $\frac{36}{720} = \frac{1}{20}$

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, shouldn't $P( 3 * vanilla)$ be $\frac{3}{10} * \frac{2}{9} * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{6}{720}$? And the same with the other three equalities?

Comment: Actually $36/720$, because the second cookie is selected at random from just $9$ cookies remaining in the jar, not $10$, and the third cookie is selected from $8$ cookies.

Comment: @Rigo Yes, it's exactly like you said.

Comment: Yeah ! Your're right ! Thank you.  I was already wondering ...